# jquery mobile: how style listview?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I can't seem to find in the stylesheet the Listview. I would like to style the heigt/margin up and down of the listview and buttons.

Does anybody know where to style this?

Comment: You could start by showing your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to change margin, not padding? When you change the margin,  background colors will not match.  Anyway, try this CSS for changing padding:

```
.ui-listview li.ui-li {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}​
```

You can update margin instead using the same CSS selector.